# isAuthenticated false passportjs on dev server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have some project on Nodejs + Express. For login on a site I use `passportjs` with his `localStrategy` .

If I login on site in my localhost, `req.isAuthenticated` return `true` and session work correct.

But when I do it on dev server, `req.isAuthenticated` return `false` and session is fall.

I try to find error on modules but they work is correct.

It is my code:

**express-session**

```
var session = require('express-session'),
express = require('express'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);

module.exports = session({
    secret: 'SECRET',
    resave: true, //don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: true, // create session until something stored
    expires: date.toUTCString(),
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly : true,
        maxAge : 30 * 60 * 1000 //30 minutes
    },
    rolling: true
});
```

**login.js**

```
exports.post = function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', { badRequestMessage: 'Error in your fields' },
    function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (user) {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                return res.format({
                    json: function () {
                        res.json({
                            link : '/personal/cabinet/'
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            return res.format({
                html: function () {
                    res.render('auth/login', {
                        error: info.message,
                        title: 'Login'
                    });
                },
                json: function () {
                    res.json(info);
                }
            });
        }
    }
  )(req, res, next);
};
```

**pasportjs**

```
var passport = require('passport'),
localStrategy = require('./strategy/localStrategy'),
models = require('models'),
Author = models.author;

//get user data for session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  Author.findOne({
    where: {
        id: user.id
    }
  }).then(function (user) {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

localStrategy(passport);

module.exports = passport.initialize();
```

**app.js**

```
...
app.use('bodyParserJson');
app.use('bodyParserUrldecoded');
app.use('cookieParser');
app.use(path.join('authPassport', 'session')); //express-session
app.use(path.join('authPassport', 'init')); //pasportjs
app.use(passport.session());

...
```

And version: 
passport: 0.3.2, 
express-session: 1.13.0, 
express: 4.13.1, 
nodejs: 4.2.6

What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have cookie issue? if host conflicts its trying to use old cookie instead creating new one. Does it happen on incognito aswell?

Comment: @dima-grossman yes, it does. now I determined that after the authentication of the passport for the first time isAuthenticated returns true, after updating the page - false. Why?